# Webstorm MAC OSX: Shortcut to move caret to page bottom or top with selection

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, osx-mavericks, webstorm

In Webstorm MAC OSX, shortcut to `Move Caret to Page Bottom/Top with Selection` is Shift + Command + **Down/Top Arrow with an equal sign**.

Please let me know where I can find the key in bold or how to use this shortcut?

Here is an image to show how it looks:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those are `page-up` and `page-down` keys.

From source:

> Page up - Smaller keyboards need to do Fn-Up Arrow to get page up.
>   Page Down - Smaller keyboards need to do Fn-Dwn Arrow to get page up.

[Source](http://tedwise.com/2009/04/28/what-do-those-weird-mac-symbols-mean)

Comment: In my Mac keyboard 'fn' is situated in the bottom left corner.